# what is the difference in the usage of the following?

Tags: differences

What is the difference in the usage of "whom" and "who"? please also tell me the rules behind their usage and some examples to clarify their difference.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, *who* refers to the subject while *whom* refers to the object of a sentence/clause.

Example:

> The person whom I talked to on the phone turned out to be the manager
>   of the restaurant.

In this case, *I* am the subject as it is me who does the action (i. e. talked on the phone) while *the person* is the object: I talked to *him*, not to *he*.

A good resource describing how to identify the subject vs the object and relating this to the whom vs who question that is not too crammed with linguistic information can be found [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-whom)

Be aware, though, that in many places *whom* is rarely used, if at all. I have heard people using *who* instead plenty of times in several different English speaking countries. This is not to say that *whom* shouldn't be used or that it is appropriate to replace it with *who*. Just be careful not to sound condescending or the like by using rarely used grammatically correct forms around people who don't use them.
In writing, of course, you can use it freely, although even in writing many people tend to use *who* instead.

Also check out the question *smithkm* has linked in a comment to your question saying your question might be a duplicate.